# IBM Server sees half of the original RAM

Tags: memory, ibm, ibm-xseries

We have a IBM XSeries 206M server. There are 2 2GB IBM RAM's which are suitable with the server. Normally we expect that server should see 4GB of RAM. But It works with 2 GB only. So we thought that one of the RAM's are probably has a problem. And removed one of them. Then server began to see only 1 GB of RAM. 
We do not have an idea why the server divides the original capacity of RAM into two.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you
FERDA

Comment: It seems that you have only 2 GB ram there. What is written on the RAM itself? Did you check that? Do you have a link to that server? maybe where you purchased it?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite likely a Memory Rank problem: The chipset cannot cope with the organization of the RAM chips. See this Q/A: [Server memory configuration after upgrade](https://serverfault.com/questions/543144/server-memory-configuration-after-upgrade/543197#543197)